# Dos and not-to-dos to no response to my resignation letter from management?

Tags: resignation

I sent my resignation letter to my in-line manager on a Thursday night, August 5th, to which he responded on Friday 6th letting me know he will forward it to HR. I returned to work on Wednesday 11th after my scheduled time off. My last day of work would be 19th based on the date I handed my notice in.

When I returned to work I tried to contact management but no one was available. My manager told me I wasn't supposed to be there and instead I should've been notified which date to go back and pick up my last check. I talked to management over the phone a couple of times and was told I would be contacted Monday 16th to set a date but there is no physical proof of anything.

I have a job offer already which I would like to accept. Technically, I am still an employee but what happens if my new job offer requires me to start asap? Also, since there was no confirmation of accepting my resignation, I have been "absent" one day, is there a difference if more days go by and I am still absent?

Resignation letter I sent was using company's laptop and phone, which I had surrendered already.

Comment: You do have a printed copy of the letter you sent? A pdf? A copy of the email? Still have access to email? Print it quickly…

Comment: Voting to close as "needs detail or clarity" until details are added about which legal jurisdiction you are in - the situation is going to be very different in India and a "right to work" state in the US.

Comment: Accept new job and stop worrying about the old.

Comment: In the future you should email your manager AND HR. In addition, don't use work equipment / accounts to do so. You should use your personal email for correspondence relating to your employment because it is personal correspondence.

Comment: @Gregory Currie I've always used my work email address to send the resignation, but CV it to my personal email address too.

Comment: @Monstar That's may be OK. Hopefully HR "Replies All" if there are any followups. required.

Answer (score 11):

Since your boss told you that he had received your resignation  then you need do nothing. You've given your required notice and there is nothing else you *have* to do. Your employer doesn't have to "accept" it for you to leave. Accept the new job starting anytime after your last day of work. Keep showing up to your old job and doing it unless you are told not to, and then on your last day say good bye.

If you are told to stop coming to work, stop coming. Make sure you have a copy of the instruction not to come to work in writing, and make sure they understand you still have to be paid when not coming to work. Keep copies of all your communication, and keep them in a place where you can get at them after you have finished work (such as on your home computer, not a work computer or the work email system). If you get any oral communication confirm it in writing.

If you are told not to come to work, ask if you are going to be needed to come back to work at any time. If not then feel free to start your new job.

But this is not a big deal. Everything I write above is for safety and you will probably be fine.

Comment: After all, resignation is a *notice*, not a *request*, unless governed by explicit contracts, isn't it?

Comment: @RomeoSierra that depends very much on the country. In an US at-will state you can just walk even without a notice, but it many other countries you have a legal requirements to serve a notice period per your contract unless you negotiate a release.

Comment: @Hilmar Right, but the point is that it's still a unilateral act (at least in the EU countries I know). It's "Dear Employer, just FYI, I'm leaving in a month or so" and very much not "Dear Employer, would you kindly please release me from service?". The employer does not get to delay your resignation indefinitely just by playing dead.

Comment: @Hilmar though your employer cannot refuse to accept your notice. The OP's line manager accepted their notice on behalf of the company. To me, it feels like the only tricky part is if the OP has a paper trail showing that if it gets sticky.

Comment: Next time accept the new job offer before resigning.  Any person who wants to hire you will gladly wait the resignation period notice if your former employer wants you working during that time.

Comment: If you are still on notice, but the employer doesn't want you in the office, just starting a new job can be problematic. In theory, the employer can change their mind and demand you spend the last days of your notice period in their office. If you propose that your last day is earlier so you can start at the other company earlier, they might accept that, but it means you won't get paid for the other days.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like they're not communicating this well, but essentially what i think is happening is, you've resigned, and they've decided it would be best not to have an employee in the office that's on their way out;

If there's nothing they need from you to ensure a transition / if your position has been made fairly replaceable, they likely are in the mindset of "Oh, okay. Well sorry to see you go, you can have this time to yourself. We'll still pay you to the end of the period. bye".

Normally this gets communicated but i suppose not in your scenario.

Regardless - you gave notice. Stick to your date , even if they ask you for more later. it's not your problem if they didn't bother preparing for the transition after your notice

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have two issues. One is that you probably wanted negotiate a shorter notice period with your employers, but it seems that no one is available. If you can't get in touch with anybody there's not much you can do. If you apply for another job just explain that you cannot start earlier, in any case it seems a reasonable wait, and that does not stop you from discussing the details of the new position or signing a contract, provided that the start date is after the end of your notice and you don't do paid work before that date. You can still begin to study the products you'll have to work with in your new role.

The other issue is tricky. If I understood correctly you didn't take a copy of the confirmation email of your boss. How to deal with this depend on what is your relationship with your former employer. In normal case you could write an email from your private address to the HR and ask for a new confirmation letter mentioning the proper dates. If on the other hand you don't trust your former employer just pretend you have a copy, it should be all right. In the extreme case you could ask to a colleague to let you access your email to get a copy.